# How to control A.exe file using B.exe

Tags: python, controls

Hellow Developer

I made A.exe program with python, using pyinstaller 
1. A.exe is running on window by display
2. i hope that control A.exe program is likely to debug mode
ex) Qwidget.information(self, "Hellow World")

What should I do?
it's mean commuication like sqlserver

If there is no way 
i think eval("Qwidget.information(self, 'Hellow World')")
but it's vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

It may need to something to communicate between two program. Create an interface for both program to interact. I think the most easy way is by setting file. A program set DEBUG mode in setting file to ON/OFF, and B program check the setting file for DEBUG mode to decide what mode to go. :-)

Comment: Thank you!! you're answer. 
I find out DEBUG mode and how to use setting file. and then apply your solution
God bless you ~